# PHP foreach, how to loop from key in array

Tags: php

I have an array returned from a DB and I'm trying to echo the output of each field, where the IDS are the same from within, and then moving on to the next ID, until finished. So it prints out all the ID "1s", then "2s", then when its finished it stops. The number of ID's is variable from 1-950.

```
array ( 0 => stdClass::__set_state(array
( 'Year' => '2017', 
'Month' => 'January',
 'name' => 'Faults', 
'id' => '1', 
'value' => '14058', )),



1 => stdClass::__set_state(array( 
'Year' => '2017',
 'Month' => 'February', 
'name' => 'Faults', 
'id' => '1', 
 'value' => '21', )),




2 => stdClass::__set_state(array
( 'Year' => '2017',
 'Month' => 'January',
 name' => 'Errors', 
'id' => '2', 'value' => '22874', )), 

3 => stdClass::__set_state(array( 
'Year' => '2017', 
'Month' => 'February', 
'name' => 'Errors',
'id' => '2',  
'value' => '2650', )), )
```

I am trying to achieve an output like this:

```
January 2017 Faults = 14958
February 2017 Faults = 21
```

HTML formatting here to break up/make a dividing row in between

```
January 2017 Errors = 22784
February 2017 Errors = 2650
```

Using this foreach syntax:

```
foreach ($results as $result) :
    if ($result->id == 1){
        echo   '<td>', $result->Month, '</td>';
```

This works but I need to update the if statement, it is not a good solution

How can I change this so it looks inside the array and only outputs the HTML for each "id"?

I've tried `foreach ($results =>id as $result)` but it doesnt work. Is this the correct idea?
What is the correct syntax?

THANKS!

Comment: RTFM : http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: why it is not a good solution ?

Comment: can you provide more data you are getting from DB

Comment: Your syntax is wrong, read the manual on how to use foreach ! `foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
    statement`

Comment: Hi Hassan it is not a good solution because I don't know how many ID's there are and it is extra work to program it. It seems better to just make it output how many it finds. Thanks!

Comment: @teeyo your comment is false. Take a look at [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: I know that I don't understand it. When it says " the second expression" 
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value) does that mean I need to ($results as $result=>$id)? This is the part thats confusing at the moment

Comment: @Not_Stepehn_hawking Can you be a little more clearer on what you want it to output?

Comment: How are you getting the data, it sounds like you want to sort the data by id before outputting, this should be done by the query, ORDER BY id ASC

Comment: I want it to output all the "times" where "id" is "x"
then if there are more "id's" in the array, keep going until it runs out of "id" to print. There might be only 1 instance of id or 20, so i thought foreach time you find "id" is the correct loop to try
I will also try @Rowan Gray suggestion so data comes in array neatly

Comment: `then if there are more "id's" in the array` can you show an example of the data in this form? Right now there can only be one ID in that object.

Comment: array ( 0 => stdClass::__set_state(array( 'Year' => '2017', 'Month' => 'January', 'name' => 'Errors', 'id' => '1', 'value' => '1234', 
 1 => stdClass::__set_state(array( 'Year' => '2017', 'Month' => 'February', 'name' => 'Errors', 'id' => '1', 'value' => '12',
2 => stdClass::__set_state(array( 'Year' => '2017', 'Month' => 'January', 'name' => 'Faults', 'id' => '2', 'value' => '94',
 1 => stdClass::__set_state(array( 'Year' => '2017', 'Month' => 'February', 'name' => 'Faults', 'id' => '2', 'value' => '75',

I just need the output to be something like, id1-January -1234
 id1-February -12

Comment: @Not_Stepehn_hawking Is that array being closed off between `'id' => '1'` and `id' => '2'` or is the array being constantly nested?

Comment: It is closed off with closing parenth between each . I only cut/pasted the relevant bits

Comment: It' still difficult to understand because I have no idea of your data structure for this array+object `array 1` appears twice as a top level. Please edit your question and include a fully formatted, none edited version

Comment: @WillParky93 Ive updated it just now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this function from the [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) documentation. This should work for you. I've sorted the array to filter by the id. We save the id and if the next one contains it, we will output the html code.

```
    $results = array_msort($results , array('id'=>SORT_ASC));

    function array_msort($array, $cols){
      $colarr = array();
     foreach ($cols as $col => $order) {
         $colarr[$col] = array();
         foreach ($array as $k => $row) { $colarr[$col]['_'.$k] = strtolower($row[$col]); }
      }
      $eval = 'array_multisort(';
      foreach ($cols as $col => $order) {
          $eval .= '$colarr[\''.$col.'\'],'.$order.',';
       }
       $eval = substr($eval,0,-1).');';
       eval($eval);
       $ret = array();
       foreach ($colarr as $col => $arr) {
           foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
               $k = substr($k,1);
              if (!isset($ret[$k])) $ret[$k] = $array[$k];
                $ret[$k][$col] = $array[$k][$col];
            }
       }
       return $ret;

    }

    $oldId = 0;
    foreach ($results as $res){
        if($oldId == $res->id){
             echo   '<td>', $res->Month, '</td>';
             //plus other output display
        }
        $oldId = $res->id;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Will. Ive tried adding this but the php seems to stop processing when the code is added. Am I right in thinking if I add it to a basic page it should just output $res-Month as it stands? thanks

Comment: I think the issue is your data structure. Because you're using an object I think it may make this solution obsolete. Is there any way you can convert the data into an array rather than an object before it gets added to `$results` @Not_Stepehn_hawking

Comment: I assume there is a way, I just wouldn;t know how. Either use a different mysql query to return a different ype or somehow convert it before looping? I might study some more on this and see what comes up. It seemed like a simple thing to do, dynamically print out as many ID's as there are. Haha isnt that often the case. Thanks

Comment: @Not_Stepehn_hawking are you getting your mysqli results like: `$result->fetch_object()` ? if so, you may be able to use `$result->fetch_assoc()` and then this solution should work.

Comment: No just 
    SELECT 
    YEAR('2017-01-01') AS Year,
    MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(1, '%m')) AS Month,
    name,
    id,
FROM
    values
       
Ill have to give it a rest for now and look at it again tomorrow thanks

Comment: Sorry @Not_Stepehn_hawking I meant the method in which you are pulling the results from query, in PHP. May you post the method where your while loop  is building the initial `$results` array?

Comment: The query is in the db so php just pulls it out by $query_id and then uses ->get and then returns $results

Comment: @Not_Stepehn_hawking I can run the conversion for you if you can post the method either in here (don't post the query text, the "SELECT YEAR(..." ) or in your OP so i can see it

Comment: public function query($id)
 {
  try {
   if(empty($id)) {
    throw new Exception('No ID.');
   }

   $query = $this->db->select('query,name')
       ->from('queries')
       ->where('id', $id)
       ->get();
      if($query->num_rows() > 0) {

    $query = $query->row();

    $run = $this->db->query($query->query);

    if($run->num_rows() > 0) {
     $results = $run->result();

Comment: Looks like a custom sql class, not sure if I can help you with this one, sorry!